# Kettle PDI Concat column values

Tags: concatenation, kettle

I have a PDI (Kettle) **transformation** that execute an SQL script, the output of scripts is a column looks like:

> val1
>
> val2
>
> val3
>
> val4
>
> "more values"...

I need write this on a only one Excel cell like this:

> val1 val2 val3 val4 "more values"...

How i can do this?

I tried "row denormaliser" and "row flattener" but dont work (i dont know why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flattener is an option, but you have problems because you do not know the number of new fields and the seperator. But there is a "trick" to solve your problem:

You can do so by following these steps:

1. Add a constant after your input, name: test, type: string, value: a
2. Group by the new field test, aggregate your field with the values with "Concatenate strings separated by" and set a space as seperator.

The output is:

val1 val2 val3 ....

Comment: thanks! just wanted to add, that in kettle 5.1 mentioned transformation steps are called 'Add constants' and 'Memory Group By' (or simple 'Group By').